# Присоедениться к вебсокету через php и прокси сервер

Tags: php

Необходими решить пробему есть www.avito.ru нужно подключиться к этому сайту, а именно его вебсокету и получать отправлять данные, через прокси сервер, как можно это сделать. Вот мои наработки

```
$proxy_ip = "21.543.54.9";
$proxy_port = 8000;
$proxyLogPass="234:43344";

$eol="\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen($proxy_ip, $proxy_port, $errno, $errstr,  5);
if (!$fp) {
    exit($errno);
}

$out = "GET www.avito.ru HTTP/1.1$eol";
$out .= "Host: www.avito.ru{$eol}";
$out .= "Connection: close$eol";
$out .= "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive$eol";
$out .= "Proxy-Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($proxyLogPass).$eol;
$out .= "Origin: *\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $out);

while (!feof($fp)) {

    echo fgets($fp, 1024);

}
fclose($fp);
```

Прошу помощи, подсказать что я не так делаю. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

а с чего вы взяли что это вообще можно делать ? у avito есть [API](https://api.avito.ru/docs/autoload/api.html#) для разработчиков, через него и делайте

Comment: То есть Вы хотите сказать, что использую прокси(SOKS5) не получиться присоедениться к вебсокету?
Api выдает информацию, но не совсем которую нужно

Comment: а кто вам даст доступ к сокету avito ?

Comment: или вы считаете что через прокси вы так же можете подключится к вебсокету банков и т.д. ?

Comment: Вы может меня не правильно поняли, я подключаюсь к вебсокету, все рботает как нужно, но я бы хотел сделать это через прокси.

Comment: @madfan41k у вас плохое представление о сокетах

Comment: Manitiky, сможете чем-то мне помочь? подскажите в каком направлении идти. Спасибо.

Comment: Сначала определите адрес связи для веб-сокета, свяжитесь с ним без прокси, а уже потом С прокси. Делайте пошагово, от одного к другому, и третьему. Протокол связи для веб-сокета обычно ws:// а не http:// (https://kaazing.com/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/)